# Jquery keyup changing value set in key down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have a select tag. ON keydown of that dropdown i'm setting some selecting some value from options as

```
$(this).find("option[value='11']").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

but it is showing `12` in dropdown, while inspecting dropdown shows option `11` as selected as

```
<option value="11" selected="selected">11</option>
```

any idea to solve this issue??

Comment: what is the point. Seems like browser default behavior??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).find("option[value='11']").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

you just missed **]**.

i didn't understand what you need actually?

if you add some description we can help you..

Answer (score 1):

You can select an element from the `select` directly through val() on the `select`:

```
$(this).val('11');
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is trying to tap into user using the arrow keys to change values, you really only need to create  a `change` event handler

```
$('select').change(function(){
   alert ($(this).val())

})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the following demos you may differentiate the `keydown` and `keyup` events.

Note: The keydown event, by definition, happens before anything else on a keypress.

**Behavior on `keydown` selects 12**

```
$('#ddwon').on('keydown', function(){
    var value = $(this).val('11');
    $(value ).attr('selected', 'selected')   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nPSja/)

**Behavior on `keyup` selects 11**

```
$('#ddwon').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = $(this).val('11');
    $(value ).attr('selected', 'selected')   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nPSja/1/)